# Error building pyside

Tags: python, qt, python-2.7, pyside

I have python 2.7 32bit installed, Qt 5.1.1 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 522 MB), cmake-2.8.12-win32-x86, Microsoft c++ 2008, openssl 1.0.1 installed.

Im following these instructions :
http://qt-project.org/wiki/Building_PySide_on_Windows

I don´t undersand why the second step is under c:/, i tryed under \pyside-setup\

I have python 2.7 system path working

C:\Users\r.prado\Desktop\PySide-1.2.0>python setup.py bdist_wininst --qmake=C:\Q
t\Qt5.1.1\5.1.1\msvc2012_64_opengl\bin\qmake.exe --openssl=C:\OpenSSL-Win32\bin

and i have this error:

http://pastebin.com/zYZvzrNs

I reinstalled setuptools, python 2.7and still getting the same error.

I don´t know what i can do.

Comment: 64-bit Qt won't be compatible with 32-bit Python. I'd start by building 32-bit Qt with VS 2008. I don't know about the error you got. You should post the error in your question.

Comment: Sounds like you try to build 1.2.0. Pyside 1.2.1 changed to setuptools 0.9.8. Maybe you could try with the latest version of pyside and setuptools to see how it goes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actual PySide version (1.2.1) does not support Qt 5.
The supported versions are Qt 4.6, 4.7 and 4.8.